# show/hide divs on click- how to make div 1 show on page load?

Tags: javascript

I have learned how to show and hide divs using javascript but how do I make the first div show on page load without having to click it?  Basically I am creating a menu with 6 different links.  I would like the first link div to show on page load and then hide when other links are clicked.

```
 <div class="nav">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li id="1"><a href="#">Topic One</a></li>
        <li id="2"><a href="#">Topic Two</a></li>
        <li id="3"><a href="#">Topic Three</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div id="1" class="content">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <p>First section of content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="2" class="content">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>        
    <p>Second section of content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="3" class="content">        
    <h1>Page 3</h1>
    <p>Third section of content.</p>
    </div>               
  </div>
 </div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$('#menu a').click(function(e){
 hideContentDivs();
 var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
 $('.main div').eq(tmp_div).show();
 });

function hideContentDivs(){
$('.main div').each(function(){
$(this).hide();});
}
hideContentDivs();
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Comment: Ids that are begin with a number are a bad idea, you won't be able to target them with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment Ids that start with a number are a bad idea, whats more you have duplicate IDs which is even worse, keep IDs unique.

There are a couple of approaches here, one is use CSS to hide the divs, then use Jquery to show them. The other is to use jQuery to hide them...as that is the path you have started down, lets use that.

But first lets fix your html

```js
$('#menu a').click(function(e){
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".main .content").not(target).hide();
    $(target).show();
    return(false);
 });

//Hide the divs on load
$(".main .content").hide();
//Set an initial target
var initialTarget = "#Section1";

//Overide that target if coming from a bookmark. E.g www.mypage.com#Section2
//Another reson to use meaningful href 
if(location.hash.length > 0) {initialTarget =location.hash; }
$(initialTarget).show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <ul id="menu">
        <!-- Give your href some actual meaning -->
        <li ><a href="#Section1">Topic One</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#Section2">Topic Two</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#Section3">Topic Three</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div id="Section1" class="content">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <p>First section of content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Section2" class="content">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>        
    <p>Second section of content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Section3" class="content">        
    <h1>Page 3</h1>
    <p>Third section of content.</p>
    </div>               
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice and help this works great!  One thing though.. how can I stop the screen from automatically scrolling down to the div area when a link is clicked?

Comment: Add `return(false);` to the click handler to disable the default action of the click.